# Сериализовать Java-объекты в JSON-строку

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

Хочу из контроллера вернуть JSON-строку `List<Items>`, но объекты в JSON сериализуются как пустые строки. В результате получаю
`[{},{}]`.

**Контроллер:**

```
@GetMapping("all")
@ResponseBody
public List<Item> all(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
    List<Item> items = itemDao.findAll();
    return items;
}
```

**Dao:**

```
@Repository
public class ItemDaoImpl implements ItemDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Item findById() {
        return em.find(Item.class, 1L);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Item> findAll() {
        List<Item> items = em.createQuery("from Item", Item.class).getResultList();
        return items;
    }
}
```

**Модель:**

```
package hello.model;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
@Data
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

}
```

Как правильно сериализовать?

Comment: добавьте методы `get/set` для полей в ваш класс `Item`

Comment: @Data создает геттеры сеттеры

Comment: Один объект нормально возвращается? Есть у вас параметр produces=Application_Json_Value? Всё большими буквами.

Comment: Объекты всегда нормально возвращаются, со всеми полями - это видно по дебагеру. Но в json сериаллизуются уже пустыми строками

Comment: Видимо, неверно выразился. Один объект тоже не сериализуется?

Comment: Да, нигде сериализация не проходит

Comment: @МаксатОрунханов а зачем `@Getter` если уже есть `@Data` ? И второе, в поле `name` есть какое-нибудь значение (не null)?

Comment: @Getter лишний. Поля объектов заполнены данными из БД. Напр, в поле name стоит строка.

Comment: Зачем аннотация @ResponsBody?

Comment: Чтобы возвращать из метода объект в браузер пользователя

Comment: @МаксатОрунханов не могу сказать что не так, залейте на гитхаб, если есть возможность, как говорится сделать минимальный воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Вкурсе, что "должна" создавать геттеры/сеттеры. Вы пробовали добавить методы `get/set`? Попробуйте. И если результат будет положительным, тогда уже понятно будет, куда надо копать.

Answer (score 1):

Аннотации надо ставить на класс

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;    
}
```